# waitpid() for non-child processes

Tags: c, linux

In C and Linux, does a similar function to waitpid exist but wait for non-child processes? I have the PID of a process (that is not my child), and I want to wait for its termination.

If it does not exist, what may be an elegant wait to perform this wait in C?

Comment: You should explain why you want to do that, and what is the process you want to wait